# How to store an object in SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an object of BluetoothDevice (flutter_blue). It does have a fromJson function, but at the same time lacks toJson. When I try to use toString() on it, it makes this output:
`{id: FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF, name: LazerDat, type: BluetoothDeviceType.le, isDiscoveringServices: false, _services: []}`

Then if I try to parse it to an object with toJson, this error appears:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
{id: FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF, name: LazerDat, type: Type.le, isDiscoveringService...
 ^
```

It tries to find the quotes but toString() does not generate them. How to add quotes to that string? Is it even possible? Are there any other ways to store a BluetoothDevice object?

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods this may help, you can create a method to a 3th party library

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsonEncode` function.

```dart
final bluetoothDevice = ...;
final encoded = jsonEncode(Bluetooth Device, 
         toEncodable: (device) {
            // return `device` properties serialized
          });
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html